# Erro ao chamar outra activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou criando um app para lançamento de frequência de alunos. O aplicativo possui comunicação com web service.

Ao clicar no botão entrar:

1. O app vai verificar se tem conexão com internet para fazer atualização dos dados do professor no SQLite, caso tenha ele irá acessar o método do web service retornar o o professor encontrado e logo depois atualizar ou inserir no banco do Android.
2. O login deve ser validado no banco do Android, caso ele encontre, ele retorna os dados e compara com os textos usuário e senha do editext, se der verdadeiro ele abre a Activity menu. **É nesse momento que a aplicação fecha com erro.**

Classe onde tem o método do click do botão

```
public class Login extends Activity {

ProfessorWS professorWS = new ProfessorWS();
Professor professor = new Professor();
ProfessorDAO professorDAO = new ProfessorDAO(this);
private EditText edUsuario, edSenha;
VerificaConexao verificaConexao = new VerificaConexao();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    edUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edUsuario);
    edSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edSenha);

}

public void btEntrarOnClick (View view){

if (verificaConexao.verificaConexao(this)){

   String msg = getString(R.string.dlg_msg);
    String titulo = getString(R.string.dlg_titulo);

    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, titulo, msg);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                LinkedHashMap<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("user", edUsuario.getText().toString());
                params.put("senha", edSenha.getText().toString());

                professor = professorWS.buscarProfessor(params);
                professorDAO.insereProfessor(professor);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

  if (edUsuario.getText().toString().equals("")||edSenha.getText().toString().equals(""))
        Toast.makeText(this,"Usuario ou senha não informados!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


   professor= professorDAO.buscarProfessorNoBanco(edUsuario.getText().toString(),edSenha.getText().toString());


     if(professor.getCodProfessor() == null)
        Toast.makeText(this,"Usuário não encontrado! Obs: o primeiro acesso deve esta conectado a rede", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else  if (professor.getUsuario().equals(edUsuario.getText().toString()) || professor.getSenha().equals(edSenha.getText().toString())) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
         startActivity(intent);
     } else
         Toast.makeText(this,"Usuário ou senha incorreto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Classe do DAO onde valida os dados

```
public class ProfessorDAO {

private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private BancoDados bancoDados;

public ProfessorDAO(Context context) {
    bancoDados = new BancoDados(context);
}

public String insereProfessor(Professor professor) {
    ContentValues valores;
    long resultado = 1;

    dataBase = bancoDados.getWritableDatabase();
    valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("CODPROF", professor.getCodProfessor());
    valores.put("NOME", professor.getNomeProfessor());
    valores.put("USUARIO", professor.getUsuario());
    valores.put("SENHA", professor.getSenha());

    resultado = dataBase.replaceOrThrow("PROFESSOR", null, valores);
    dataBase.close();

    if (resultado == -1)
        return "Erro de registro";
    else
        return "Registro Inserido com sucesso";

}


public Professor buscarProfessorNoBanco(String usuario, String senha) {


    Cursor cursor = dataBase.query("PROFESSOR", null, "USUARIO = ? AND SENHA = ?", new String[]{usuario, senha}, null, null, null);
    Professor professor = null;
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        professor = new Professor();
        professor.setCodProfessor(cursor.getString(0));
        professor.setNomeProfessor(cursor.getString(1));
        professor.setUsuario(cursor.getString(2));
        professor.setSenha(cursor.getString(3));
    } else {
        Log.i("Erro:", "Erro no if do cursor");
    }
    cursor.close();
  return professor;
    }
}
```

Erro

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: feol.com.br.diarioclasse, PID: 20105
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                          at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4025)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785) 
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at feol.com.br.diarioclasse.ProfessorDAO.buscarProfessorNoBanco(ProfessorDAO.java:46)
                                                                          at feol.com.br.diarioclasse.Login.btEntrarOnClick(Login.java:68)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020) 
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785) 
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: cade o seu debug?

Comment: Qual é o erro? Em qual linha está ocorrendo?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida pois é sem o debug do codigo dele não tem como saber! pode ser a atvidade que ele esta chamando que não existe! mas  fica  meio dificil saber

Comment: Coloquei o erro na pergunta